# Joint Distribution function and joint density function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am really confused with what the question is asking and where to start. Thanks in advance for help.

Suppose $(a,b) $~uniform$([0,1]\times[0,1])$  (Does that mean we are given the join density function?)

1. Determine the cdf $F: R^2 \to [0,1]$
2. Determine the density $f$ from $F$.

Comment: This is a rather non-standard notation but my take is that the pair $(a,b)$ has the joint distribution: $f_{a,b}(x,y)=1$ if $0\le x\le1$ and $0\le y\le 1$; $f_{a,b}(x,y)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Yes, the joint density is $1$ on the square. The problem undoubtedly specifies what $R^2$ is, but that got left out of the post. It probably is $a^2+b^2$, but you should make that clear.

Comment: $R$ is likely the set of real numbers (typically denoted $\mathbb R$).

Comment: You meant joint distriubtion function??

Comment: And yes, R is the set of real numbers.

Comment: And $R^2=R\times R$, as is natural for the source set of the CDF of a pair of real valued random variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're given that $(A,B)$ have joint uniform distribution on the unit square $$\mathcal D :=[0,1]\times[0,1] = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: 0\leqslant x, y\leqslant 1\}. $$
It follows that for any Borel set $S\subset\mathbb R^2$, $$\mathbb P((A,B)\in S) = \lambda(S\cap\mathcal D),$$
where $\lambda$ is $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. The joint distribution function is given by 
$$
F_{X,Y}(x,y) = (x\wedge 1)\mathsf 1_{[0,\infty)}(x)(y\wedge 1)\mathsf 1_{[0,\infty)}(y)
$$
where denotes $\wedge$ denotes $\min$ and $\mathsf 1$ the indicator function. Since the joint distribution satisfies $F_{X,Y} = F_XF_Y$ (the product of the marginal distribution functions), $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so the joint density satisfies $f_{X,Y}=f_Xf_Y$. Now, $$f_X(x) = \frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dx}F_X(x) = \mathsf 1_{[0,1]}(x)$$ and similarly $f_Y(y)=\mathsf 1_{[0,1])}(y)$, so
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \mathsf 1_{[0,1]}(x)\mathsf 1_{[0,1]}(y). $$

Comment: would it be possible for you to help me with this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2513378/how-to-get-joint-probability-density-from-bivariate-distribution-function You really seem to know what you're doing with bivariate distributions and I could learn a lot from you! Thanks :)