# How to get joint probability density from bivariate distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_{i} \sim \varepsilon(\lambda_{i}), i = 1,2,3$ be mutually independent ($\varepsilon$ means exponential, $\lambda_{i}$'s are parameters). Then $(T_{1},T_{2}) = (X_{1} \wedge X_{3}, X_{2} \wedge X_{3})$ has a bivariate Marshall-Olkin exponential survival function, for $t_{1}\geq 0$ and $t_{2} \geq 0$:

$$ \overline{F}(t_{1},t_{2})=P(T_{1}>t_{1},\, T_{2}>t_{2}) = P(X_{1}>t_{1},\, X_{2}>t_{2}, X_{3}>t_{1} \vee t_{2}) \\ = \exp\{-\lambda_{1}t_{1}-\lambda_{2}t_{2} - \lambda_{3}(t_{1} \vee t_{2})\} $$

I need to derive the joint probability density function $f(t_{1},t_{2})$ for this distribution function $\overline{F}$, and then compute $\int \int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}^{2}}f(t_{1},t_{2})dt_{1}dt_{2}$, and then say whether there is anything strange about my answer.

Usually, in the case of one variable, to get from a distribution function $F$ to a probability density function $f$, I would take the derivative of $F$. However, in the case of two variables, I am not sure what to do - do I take partial derivatives of $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$? How does the $\vee$ operator impact that?

Then, I assume I have to integrate them again, and I'm guessing that the "strange" part is that when I integrate, I'm not going to get back my original $\overline{F}$, possibly because the $X_{i}$ are mutually independent.

But, like I said, I am not sure how to formally go about showing any of these things, primarily because of the multivariate nature of this problem, and because the relationship between the $X_{i}$ and the $T_{i}$ is confusing me.

Could somebody please help me finish this? I am extremely confused and very much in need of guidance! Thank you!

Comment: You take the cross partial derivatives with respect to $t_1, t_2$, on the joint CDF $F$, then you will obtain the joint pdf. If you take integration from $-\infty$ to $t_1, t_2$ respectively then you obtain the joint CDF back.

Comment: @BGM what is a cross partial derivative?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Densities_associated_with_multiple_variables For the maximum part, you just treat it as a piece-wise function.

Comment: Yes, that's the approach. Make sure though to firstly compute F itself in the sense that you write it in terms of \hat F, it's not too difficult (draw a picture), but results in a slightly more complicated expression.

Comment: @BGM I'm not sure what you mean by "for the maximum part", but apparently. I need to find the mixed partials? By "maximum", do you mean the $\vee$? I think my inability to visualize what this is supposed to look like on paper might be because we have different terminologies for the same thing and are not realizing it. Can you write out this maximum part as a piecewise function for me so I will understand what you are talking about? Thank you.

Comment: @BGM also, am I right about the something strange?

Comment: I mean $\displaystyle\max\{t_1, t_2\} = \begin{cases} t_2 &, t_1 \leq t_2 \\ t_1 &, t_1 > t_2 \end{cases}$. I am not sure what do you feel strange.

Comment: @BGM I found this: http://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/25781/14/14_chapter%206.pdf I am trying to get what they have on the bottom of p. 103 on my own, but I'm having trouble. Did they get the cases backwards? It seems to me their case for $t_{1}>t_{2}$ should be for $t_{2}>t_{1}$? Could you do one of the partial derivatives out as an answer so I can try to figure out how a cross partial is supposed to be done? I'd accept that as an answer.

Comment: When $t_1 > t_2$, $\displaystyle \begin{align} f_{X_1, X_2}(t_1, t_2) &= \frac {\partial^2} {\partial t_1 \partial t_2} F_{X_1, X_2}(t_1, t_2) \\ &= \frac {\partial^2} {\partial t_1 \partial t_2} \bar{F}_{X_1, X_2}(t_1, t_2) \\ &= \frac {\partial^2} {\partial t_1 \partial t_2} \exp\{-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_3)t_1 - \lambda_2t_2\} \\ & = (\lambda_1 + \lambda_3)\lambda_2\exp\{-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_3)t_1 - \lambda_2t_2\} \\ &= (\lambda_1 + \lambda_3)\lambda_2\bar{F}(t_1, t_2) \end{align}$

Comment: @BGM thank you! Now, for integrating everything back, how do I handle all the cases?

Comment: @BGM what I mean is, do you integrate each piece separately?

Comment: If you do the integration, you just get the reverse step in the above calculation and get back the joint CDF. $\displaystyle F_{X_1, X_2}(t_1, t_2) = \int_{-\infty}^{t_1} \int_{-\infty}^{t_2} f_{X_1, X_2}(u_1, u_2)du_2du_1$

Comment: @BGM well, it's done and it's handed in. After integrating the three parts separately, I didn't get back exactly the CDF back for any of them, but at this point, it is what it is. I still would like to see in detail how to do this part, though, so I'd know it for next time. So, in 14 hours, when I can put  a bounty on this question, I will. If you want to be the one who answers it, great.

Comment: I am not sure whats wrong in your calculation, but make sure you know there is a difference between $F$ and $\bar{F}$, and after integration you will get the CDF $F$, although both have the same anti-derivatives.

Comment: @BGM aah, that I did not know. I kept a copy of my assignment. I'll try fixing it, but still, if you want to post an answer once the bounty goes up, it couldn't hurt. In each one, there were a few extra $e$ terms and a $+1$.

Comment: @BGM the bounty is up.