# Calculating expected value and dealing with an indeterminate form

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions, improper-integrals

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable with the Pareto Distribution, and say that its density function is given by $$f(x) = \frac{a b^{a}}{x^{a+1}},\, \text{for}\, x \geq b,\,a > 0,\,\text{and}\,b>0 $$

I am trying to calculate the $E(X)$ for all possible values of $a$.

To that effect, I have set up and evaluated the following integral:
$$E(X) = \int_{b}^{\infty} x f(x) dx = \int_{b}^{\infty} \frac{xa b^{a}}{x^{a+1}}dx = a b^{a} \int_{b}^{\infty} x^{-a}dx \\ = a b^{a}\left[ \frac{x^{-a+1}}{-a+1}\right]_{b}^{\infty} = \frac{a b^{a}}{1-a}\cdot \lim_{c \to \infty}\left[\frac{1}{x^{a-1}} \right]_{b}^{c} = \frac{ab^{a}}{1-a}\left(\lim_{c \to \infty} \frac{1}{c^{a-1}} - \frac{b}{b^{a}} \right) \\ = \left(\frac{ab^{a}}{1-a}\lim_{c \to \infty} \frac{1}{c^{a-1}}\right) - \frac{ab}{1-a}$$

Now, when $a-1>0$, or $a > 1$, this converges to $$0 - \frac{ab}{(1-a)} = \frac{ab}{a -1} $$

When $a-1 < 0$, or $a < 0$, the integral diverges, so in this case, $E(X) = \infty$.

However, when $a - 1 = 0$, or $a = 1$, we have that $\displaystyle E(X) = \frac{ab^a}{1-a} - \frac{ab}{1-a} = \frac{a(b^a-b)}{1-a}$ When $a=1$ then, this becomes $\frac{0}{0}$. From Wikipedia, I have since learned that that for $a=1$, $E(X) = \infty$ as well, but how do we figure that out from this indeterminate form that we get upon substituting in $a = 1$? Is it because in the numerator, we have exponentials, and so they grow to infinity faster than the linear terms in the denominator? I want to understand how to justify this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must integrate the case for $a = 1$ separately:

$$E(X) = \int_{b}^{\infty} \frac{x(1)b^{1}}{x^{1+1}}dx = \int_{b}^{\infty} \frac{xb}{x^2}dx = b \int_{b}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}dx = b\cdot \lim_{c \to \infty}\left[ln(x)\right]_{b}^{c} \\= b\lim_{c \to \infty}[\ln(c) - \ln(b)] = b\lim_{c \to \infty}\ln(c) - b\lim_{c \to \infty}ln(b) = b \lim_{c \to \infty} ln(c) - b \ln(b) \\= b \lim_{c \to \infty}\ln(c) - \ln(b)^{b} = \infty - \ln(b)^b = \infty $$

Comment: This is true. Integration of $x^{-a}$ is **always** a special case when $a=1$.

Comment: @A.Γ. have you seen the bounty I have up? It's this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2513378/how-to-get-joint-probability-density-from-bivariate-distribution-function